# Unsuppored ID type class java.util.UUID in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use spring-data-elasticsearch in my Jhipster project.
My entity type has an id field of type java.util.UUID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "item")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "myUUIDGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "myUUIDGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id;


    @Column(name = "item_name")
    private String itemName;

    // setters & getters
}
```

This has a repository associated as follows

```
import java.util.UUID;
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item,UUID> {

}
```

This also has a search repository associated with it

```
import java.util.UUID;
public interface ItemSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Item, UUID> {
}
```

When I am running the application, I am getting the following error.

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'itemResponseSearchRepository': 
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsuppored ID type class java.util.UUID
```

I have tried with both spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch as well as spring-data-elasticsearch.

The sample pom entries are given below.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

OR

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
  <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

But I am still getting the "Unsuppored ID type class java.util.UUID" error. The database I am using is MySQL

Comment: There was a PR about exactly this issue [that was merged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/135) a while ago. Which version of Spring Data ES are you using?

Comment: Yess, I saw that. I upgraded my version to spring-data-elasticsearch to 3.0.0.M1 and it solved the issue